# how to set childlayouts as vertical in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

**how to set childlayouts as vertical in linearlayout**

i want to set linearparent as horizontal and i have successfully done it ..
But i also want to set linearlayouts vertically linearChild But unable to dont it ... any help would be appreciated

```
    package "";



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Random random;
    ArrayList<String[]> list;
    public static String string;
    LinearLayout child;
    LinearLayout linearParent, linearChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        random = new Random();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        string = Home.string;


        linearParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        linearChild = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child);
        child = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        addparentview(string);
        ReadChar(string);


    }

    public void ReadChar(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character c = s.charAt(i);
            String character = c.toString();
            Log.e("char", String.valueOf(character));
            if (character.equals("a") || character.equals("A")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("b") || character.equals("B")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.b);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("c") || character.equals("C")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.c);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("d") || character.equals("D")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.d);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("e") || character.equals("E")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("f") || character.equals("F")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.f);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("g") || character.equals("G")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.g);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("h") || character.equals("H")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.h);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("i") || character.equals("I")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.i);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("j") || character.equals("J")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.j);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("k") || character.equals("K")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.k);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("l") || character.equals("L")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.l);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("m") || character.equals("M")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.m);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("n") || character.equals("N")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.n);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("o") || character.equals("O")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.o);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("p") || character.equals("P")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.p);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("q") || character.equals("Q")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("r") || character.equals("R")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.r);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("s") || character.equals("S")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.s);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("t") || character.equals("T")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.t);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("u") || character.equals("U")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.u);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("v") || character.equals("V")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.v);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("w") || character.equals("W")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.w);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("x") || character.equals("X")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.x);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("y") || character.equals("Y")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.y);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("z") || character.equals("Z")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.z);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);
            }
        }
        linearChild.addView(child);

    }

    public void addView(String string) {
        child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parentparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        child.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        child.setLayoutParams(parentparams);
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            Character c = string.charAt(i);
            String character = c.toString();
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(character);
            child.addView(textView);
        }
    }

    public void addparentview(String string) {
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            Character c = string.charAt(i);
            String character = c.toString();
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(character);
            textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            linearParent.addView(textView);
        }

    }
}
```

> below is the output i want

[image: result i want]

> below is the output i got from above code

[image: result i got from above code]

Comment: i have did but didnt get desired out put see code

Comment: I think you should set orientation for your parent view instead of child view

Comment: Hey I didn't understand which your current output and which  is your goal

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud question edited .... see plz

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a [Grid View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) ?

You can also use a [recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) with gridview layout.

Comment: i  m creating linearlayouts according to string length .... and more.... that isnot possiblw with gridview bro ....... don't  judge only by seeing picture .. read question and code properly....

Comment: Well, seems like I didn't get what you want to obtain: like some kind of matrix ? 2 dimension table ?

Answer (score 0):

I Changed only the init of the Child Linear layout to ReadChar Method
and used equalsIgnoreCase insted of make two conditions

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Random random;
    ArrayList<String[]> list;
    public static String string;
    LinearLayout child;
    LinearLayout linearParent, linearChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        random = new Random();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        string = "GERA";


        linearParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        linearChild = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child);
        addparentview(string);
        ReadChar(string);


    }

    public void ReadChar(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            child = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

            Character c = s.charAt(i);
            String character = c.toString();
            Log.e("char", String.valueOf(character));
            if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("b") ) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.b);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("c") || character.equals("C")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.c);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("d") || character.equals("D")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.d);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.e);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            } else if (character.equals("f") || character.equals("F")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.f);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            }
            else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("g")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.f);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            }
            else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
                String[] a = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.f);
                String randomStr = a[new Random().nextInt(a.length)];
                addView(randomStr);
                Log.e("random", randomStr);

            }
            linearChild.addView(child);
        }
    }

    public void addView(String string) {
        child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parentparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        child.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        child.setLayoutParams(parentparams);
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            Character c = string.charAt(i);
            String character = c.toString();
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(character);
            child.addView(textView);
        }
    }

    public void addparentview(String string) {
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            Character c = string.charAt(i);
            String character = c.toString();
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(character);
            textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            linearParent.addView(textView);
        }

    }
}
```

And this the Layout file I used

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.repo51.stackoverflow41143864.MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Note as @wOOly mentioned this can achieved using recycle view I will try to make example for it in the future

Comment: @beginner feedback?